# I can't make an entity. (Roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

Alright, so this might seem easy, but it wont stop trying to index nil for character, or it just wont move, or it'll move, but wont kill the targeted player (Theres only one allowed in a server at a time.)

I will describe what the entity is like before I show the current code that I have for it. This entity is meant to spawn around the player after a long but random amount of time. This monster can phase through walls so the only ways to get away from it is to run far enough away or shine it with a flashlight. This entity has a customizable speed counter that controls how fast it moves (obviously). I keep having errors with its main code so I cant test it out.

This is the code I have for it.

```
local entity = script.Parent
 
local speed = 10

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer 

local function chasePlayer()
  local humanoid = player.Character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")

  if humanoid then
    local targetPosition = humanoid.RootPart.Position
    local direction = (targetPosition - entity.Position).unit

    entity.Velocity = direction * speed
  end
end

entity.Touched:Connect(function(otherPart)
  local character = otherPart.Parent
  local humanoid = character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")

  if humanoid then
    humanoid.Health = 0
  end
end)

game:GetService("RunService").Heartbeat:Connect(chasePlayer)
```

I would like for someone to correct this code as I have tried countless times to get it to work but have failed miserably.

I tried defining player and I was expecting it to move the part towards my character and kill it but it didn't do anything even though there were no errors.

Comment: [`unit`](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/datatypes/Vector3#Unit) should be upper case. Did you debug whether the heartbeat function is called, and humanoid is not nil? What type of script is this (localscript, modulescript, ...)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to target only one specific client that all clients can see moving you will need a RemoteEvent to be fired in a completely different LocalScript (which is protected because cheaters could exploit this, with checks like seeing if they are actually the one the game is really trying to make get chased), because if this is a LocalScript, only one client will see the entity chasing them, while other clients see the entity standing still, also I see you didn't use Humanoid:MoveTo(vector3), instead of using velocities (which are supposed to be vector3) and to fix your issue I would recommend using Part:ApplyImpulse instead of changing velocity.

Unit is supposed to have uppercase U or it wont work by the way.
So thats your solution.

Here is my version of your code which is fixed.
Keep in mind only the client can see the entity chasing them, not the other clients.

Entities are impossible to make (difficult) without them having basic components of a regular Roblox player character.

If your entity doesn't have components of a regular roblox character, recommend adding now then using this script.

```
    local entity = script.Parent

    local speed = 10

    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer 

    local function chasePlayer()
      local humanoid = player.Character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
      if not entity then return end
      if humanoid then
         coroutine.wrap(function()
          local bool = true
          -- add parameters to make this value false when you want it to
             while bool == true do
            wait()
            -- I'm beginning to think this entity doesnt have a humanoid but lets assume it does and this is a part of it's body. 
            entity.Parent.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = speed
            if player.Character.Humanoid.RootPart then  
               entity.Parent.Humanoid:MoveTo(player.Character.Humanoid.RootPart.Position)
            end
         end
         end)()
      end
    end

    entity.Touched:Connect(function(otherPart)
      local character = otherPart.Parent
      local humanoid = character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")

      if humanoid then
        humanoid.Health = 0
      end
    end)

    chasePlayer()

    -- game:GetService("RunService").Heartbeat:Connect(chasePlayer) -- ehh i would recommend removing this and replacing it with just chasePlayer() because i added a corountine.wrap() so it'll put pressure on the client and add lag.
```